# Unable to find assembly within same project and DLL while deserialize

Tags: c#

I  **Serialize** the number of different list of classes inside from one single class. Serialize function work properly but **Deserialize** function not working properly.

> Error : " Unable to find assembly 'SEPL.AutoDCRBIM, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Both functions are running in same project not different project.

Comment: which serializer do you use

Comment: ` using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    //bin.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();                   
                    bin.Serialize(stream, clsCheckModelErrors.bimdcr);
                }`

Answer (score 0):

BinaryFormatter works with type information.A type is defined by its assembly. Thus "SomeType in AssemblyA" is completely different to "SomeType in AssemblyB", even if they happen to have been compiled from the same source file.

use XMLSerializer instead which is contract-based serializer where classes that look similar enough are fine, even if they are in different assemblies

Comment: i am using same DLL not like Type A and Type B.

Comment: Both serialize and deserialize functions are using the same assembly which is a class file in the project.
but no luck. The thing which is weird is that the serialize function works well. it is just the deserialize function.

I even put both functions as a continues code in one function again serialize works but deserialize choose to not to work.

Comment: did u try xmlserializer??

Comment: no....actually i cant use xmlserializer because most of DLL area shared among the different project only specific project give  that issue in other project it works fine...